# Xml serialization add element with properties

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have two classes:

```
public class A
{
    [XmlElement("Content")]
    public B SomeName { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int X { get; set; }
}
```

It serializes into xml like this:

```
<A>
  <Content X="5" />
</A>
```

I would like to specify element name in Content and gets something like this

```
<A>
  <Content>
      <Some element X="5" />
  </Content>
</A>
```

Can i do this without creating new class witch will contains B using standart xml serialization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option you have is to declare the `SomeName` property in class `A` as a collection of objects of type `B` and then make use of the `[XmlArray]` and `[XmlArrayItem]` attributes.

Here is a working example. Be aware that I changed the property `SomeName` to `SomeNames`.

```
[Serializable]
public class A
{
    [XmlArray("Content")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Some")]
    public List<B> SomeNames { get; set; } = new List<B>();
}

public class B
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "element")]
    public int X { get; set; }
}

public static void XmlSerialize()
{
    var a = new A {SomeNames = new List<B> {new B() {X = 5}}};
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(A));
    var settings = new XmlWriterSettings() {Indent = true};
    using var stream = XmlWriter.Create("serialized.xml", settings);
    serializer.Serialize(stream, a);
}
```

The result produced by this example will be as desired by you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<A xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Content>
    <Some element="5" />
  </Content>
</A>
```